# Check if any of effects is playing in Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml, effects

I have some effects which I use in my Flex app... They are all declared within mxml tags...
For example:

```
<mx:Fade id="fadeIn" alphaTo="1" duration="500"/>
<mx:Fade id="fadeOut" alphaTo="0" duration="500"/>
<mx:Move id="moveEffect" duration="500"/>
<mx:Rotate id="rotateEffect" duration="500"/>
```

Usually, when I trigger some effect, I want to disable all interaction if any of effects is playing, so I would like to know is there a way to check such thing in actionscript besides

```
if (!fadeIn.isPlaying && !fadeOut.isPlaying && !moveEffect.isPlaying && !rotateEffect.isPlaying)
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your effects with `Array` or `Vector`:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Vector id="effects" type="mx.effects.Effect">
        <mx:Fade id="fadeIn" alphaTo="1" duration="500"/>
        <mx:Fade id="fadeOut" alphaTo="0" duration="500"/>
        <mx:Move id="moveEffect" duration="500"/>
        <mx:Rotate id="rotateEffect" duration="500"/>
    </fx:Vector>
</fx:Declarations>

private function isEffectPlaying():Boolean
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < effects.length; i++)
    {
        if (effects[i].isPlaying)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```